# Turning Function into a shortcode - Wordpress

Tags: php, sql, shortcode, wordpress

So I'm using this function below that works perfectly, however I want to convert it into a wordpress shortcode.

```
<?php
if( have_rows('pdf_download') ):
    while ( have_rows('pdf_download') ) : the_row(); ?>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('pdf_download'); ?>">File Download</a></li> 
        </ul>
        <?php

    endwhile;

else :

endif;

?>
```

With the shortcode I'm creating I have different cases this is gonna be used for my custom taxonomy. All of the pages where I would use this function have a body class with single-prod and a postid-## . I was thinking about writing cases that target the specific post Id numbers that I want. I have something similar to this if anyone can help me

```
function data_prod($atts) {

    global $post;

    switch($post->ID) {
        // Xbox One
        case 29:
            $query = new WP_Query(array(Do Something HERE));
            break;
        // Iphone 6s
        case 25:
            $query = new WP_Query(array(Do Something HERE));
            break;
        // iWatch
        case 17:
            $query = new WP_Query(array(Do Something HERE));
            break;
    }

    $content = '';
    $content .= '<ul>';
        while($query->have_rows('pdf_download')) : $query->the_row();
            $content .= '<li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('pdf_download'); ?>">File Download</a></li> ';
        endwhile;
    $content .= '</ul>';

    return $content;
}
add_shortcode('data_prod', 'data_prod');
```

Comment: What are you asking? your question isn't clear! also your first 'function' is not a function. Its a loop.

Comment: @MarkP I want to turn that first loop into a shortcode where I can create cases to display that loop on the particular postid number I call.

Answer (score 0):

Put the first code in a function, lets say yourLoopFunction:

```
function yourLoopFunction() {
 if( have_rows('pdf_download') ):
while ( have_rows('pdf_download') ) : the_row(); ?>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="<?php the_sub_field('pdf_download'); ?>">File Download</a></li> 
    </ul>
    <?php

endwhile;

 else :

endif;
}
```

Then add:

```
add_shortcode('myLoop', 'yourLoopFunction');
```

This will create the shortcode [myloop] that you can use.

All this should be in your functions.php for a custom file linked to from your functions.php file.

Your first stop should be: [Wordpress Shortcode API](https://codex.wordpress.org/Shortcode_API) to look at getting attributes etc...

Comment: Forgot to add, be careful when playing with loops in your functions file. In fact be careful with your functions file altogether.

Comment: so I wouldn't need to do those cases? How would it know which pdf files to post on which page?

Comment: you woud use the shortcode attributes - look at the link I sent. Then you can pass stuff in the shortcode like [myLoop pdf="123"] or whatever...